# Add an action to an already existing iot rule through AWS CDK

Tags: aws-cdk

I am trying to add an action to an already existing IoT Rule through AWS CDK. I have looked at the documentation, but found nothing. I am reaching out to the community to know if there is a way to do this

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately You can not modify existing resources through AWS CDK.
Watch out because the `synth`  fails silently.
Look at this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/6548) for more clarification.